# Is C(a,b) a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that C[a,b] the set of continuous functions from the closed interval [a,b] to R is a vector space.
What about the C(a,b) the set of continuous functions from the open interval (a,b) to R ?

Comment: In checking $C[a,b]$ is a vector space did you ever use any property of $[a,b]$?

Comment: In general $C(X,\Bbb R)$ is a vector space for $X\neq \emptyset$

Comment: @learnmore: actually $X = \emptyset$ gives you a vector space too.

Comment: @RobArthan;I actually don't know if  you can give any structure on a empty set or not;I feel then you can't define a function on $X$

Comment: @Arthan but there will be no 0 element

Comment: @learnmore $C(\emptyset,\mathbb R)$ isn't empty; it has one function, which is the empty function.

Comment: How is it defined "empty function"@MiloBrandt

Comment: @learnmore You can type "empty function" into a search engine.

Comment: @learnmore Well, you can define a function $A\rightarrow B$ as a subset $f$ of $A\times B$ such that for every $x\in A$, there exists precisely one $y\in B$ such that $(x,y)\in f$ - and one then writes $f(x)=y$. If $A$ is empty, then you can take $f$ to be the empty set. As there are no $x\in A$, this vacuously satisfies the condition for a function, so is a function.

Comment: That's really nice ;I googled it .Thanks ,I learned a new thing @MiloBrandt

Comment: @WeiYang: $C(\emptyset, \Bbb{R}) = \Bbb{R}^0 = \{0\}$, where $0$ is the only possible function from $0 = \emptyset$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and the proof is essentially the same. Given a continuous function $f$ on $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for any constant $k$ the product $k f(x)$ is also a continuous function on $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Similarly, given two continuous functions $f$ and $g$ from $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, their sum and difference are continuous functions from $(a,b)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

The various other axioms of a vector space can be checked similarly, and the methods are identical to the case for continuous functions on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the definition of vector space for the nonempty collection of continuous functions on an open interval to $\Bbb{R}$?

- The zero function is a continuous function and acts as an additive identity.
- The sum of continuous functions is continuous.
- Addition is associative and commutative in $\Bbb{R}$, so is associative and commutative in this collection.
- The pointwise negative of a continuous function is continuous, so additive inverses are in this collection.
- A scalar multiple of a continuous functions is continuous.
- Since products occur pointwise in $\Bbb{R}$, scalar and vector multiplications are compatible.
- Scalar multiplication by $1$ is the identity in this collection.
- Both distributive operations are performed in $\Bbb{R}$, so both work.

That is, it is immediate from the definition that the collection of continuous functions from an open set to $\Bbb{R}$ is a vector space.